# Electret microphone to speaker noise

Tags: filter, microphone, lm386

I have been working on a circuit where part of the work involves an electret microphone that gets the input signal and outputs it through a speaker. It happens to have noise emanating from the speaker. I have tried different RC filter circuits but the noise is still there no matter what. I really need help. Below is an image of the circuit[image]

Comment: Noise (sound of the wind blowing) or a howling sound that changes as you move the speaker or microphone around?

Comment: @JRE likely suspects audio feedback from speaker-to-Mic - that's quite possible. Another possible cause: have you forgotten to add a bypass capacitor between pin 6 and pin 4? These chips often oscillate when Vcc path and GND path are too long. Try adding a 0.1uf capacitor very close to the chip.

Comment: The power supply voltage moves up and down a little from the speaker current going up and down. R2 passes the voltage fluctuations directly to the amplifier input then amplifies them. Add a series 1k resistor between R2 and the power supply voltage and a 47uF capacitor to ground between the resistors to filter away the voltage fluctuations.

Comment: Waya, you are using a high gain setting (1 & 8 bypassed) and have nothing on pin 7, which I think you need. Also, the datasheet says, *"When using the LM386 with higher gains (bypassing the 1.35 kΩ resistor between pins 1 and 8) it is necessary
to bypass the unused input, preventing degradation of gain and possible instabilities."*

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have acoustical feedback howling.
The mic can hear the speaker and causes sounds to go around and around. Out the speaker and into the mic, amplified then out the speaker and into the mic, over and over.

Record the sounds with the speaker turned off them play back the sounds with the mic turned off, the same as a cheap intercom.

Increasing the supply voltage from 9V to 12v barely increases the output power. Instead it nearly doubles the amount of heating and supply current.
[image: LM386]